# I Can't Get Inbound Connections to My Node

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, connection, raspberry-pi

I recently set up a Bitcoin Core Node on a Raspberry Pi. It is fully caught up to the chain tip and has 10 outbound connections. I am using bitcoind to configure the node and have not been able to get inbound connections. Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Firewalls are turned off.
2. I've set up port forwarding on my router to port 8333.
3. I've added listen=1 and discover=1 in bitcoin.conf
4. I created a static ip address on my router.
5. I rebooted the router and bitcoind.
6. Checked my ISP for blocked ports and 8333 is not blocked.

When I check bitnodes.io, I get a message that port 8333 is unreachable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was unaware that Uncomplicated Firewall ufw was installed on my Raspberry Pi. When I ran the command below I found the following.

```
sudo ufw status verbose

Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

This showed me that is was active and only allowing action from port 22 for SSH. To correct this I opened ports 8333 for MAINET and 18333 for TESTNET with the following commands.

```
sudo ufw allow 8333 comment "Bitcoin mainnet"

sudo ufw allow 18333 comment "Bitcoin testnet"
```

This change the ufw configuration to the following and now inbound connections have been created.

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
8333                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # Bitcoin mainnet
18333                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # Bitcoin testnet
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
8333 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # Bitcoin mainnet
18333 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # Bitcoin testnet
```